# How can I write this range in set notation?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

This may pose as a very obvious question, but  I'm kind of new to set theory and don't really know all too much. Suppose you have the function $y=x^2+3$. Let the set of all numbers which $y$ could be (the range) be $R$. Therefore, $y$ is a real number that is greater than or equal to $3$. So would it be accurate to write this set as

$$R=\{y∈\mathbb{R}:y≥3\}$$

I'm not sure if a comma should be used in place of a colon here. Thanks.

Comment: Your approach seems fine.  Alternative would be $~\{ ~(x^2 + 3) ~: ~x \in \Bbb{R} ~\}.$

Comment: Another option uses interval notation: $[3,\infty)$.

Comment: Your definition of $R$ is a good, standard notation to define such a set. Other notations that are similar to this are $\{y\in\mathbb{R} \mid y\leq3\}$, $\{y \mid y\in\mathbb{R},y\leq3\}$, and $\{y : y\in\mathbb{R},y\leq3\}$. The last two examples are classic set-builder notation, to be read "$y$ such that (whatever is on the right side of the colon or vertical line)." Notations like yours are a commonly used abbreviation, read "$y$ in $\mathbb R$ such that ... ." Do **not** just replace the colon with a comma, because that could cause confusion.

Comment: @DavidK Great, thanks a lot.

Comment: @DavidK You used the opposite inequality sign in your comment.

Comment: @jjagmath Yes, I see that now. I would fix it, but one can't edit comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is fine. In fact, you have solved for the range of $f$ explicitly.

Now, suppose that we do not know how to solve for the range, we can then leave it as

$$\{x^2+3: x \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

If the domain is not $\mathbb{R}$, we can just change the domain in the set notation easily, for example, if the domain is $\mathbb{N}$, then we can just write

$$\{x^2+3: x \in \mathbb{N}\}.$$